# Datagrid inserted row without leaving the row is always empty

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I was wondering if it is possible or its just me hoping for something not realizable.

I'm explaining my problem:

I have a `Datagrid` as simple as it could be:

```
<DataGrid Background="Transparent" RowBackground="MidnightBlue" 
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White" VerticalGridLinesBrush="White"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          SelectionMode="Single" CanUserSortColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Patrols}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPatrol}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCell}"
                                EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridTextBox}"
                                Binding="{Binding Phone}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="20"
                                   Text="Gsm"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
             <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Height="30" Width="30" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext, Converter={StaticResource IsNamedObjectVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"
                                    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.InsertOrUpdateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                    ToolTip="Enregistrer">      
                                <Image Source="../../Images/Save.png"/>
                            </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</Grid>
```

There are my properties in viewModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Patrol> _patrols;
    public ObservableCollection<Patrol> Patrols
    {
        get { return _patrols; }
        set { Set(() => Patrols, ref _patrols, value); }
    }

    private Patrol _selectedPatrol;
    public Patrol SelectedPatrol
    {
        get { return _selectedPatrol; }
        set { Set(() => SelectedPatrol, ref _selectedPatrol, value); }
    }

    private ICommand _insertOrUpdateCommand;
    public ICommand InsertOrUpdateCommand
    {
        get { return _insertOrUpdateCommand = _insertOrUpdateCommand ?? new RelayCommand(InsertOrUpdatePatrol); }
    }
```

Then my function where i'm supposed to retreive my new object from selectedItem property:

```
    private void InsertOrUpdatePatrol()
    {
        var patrolProcessor = new PatrolProcessor();
        patrolProcessor.InsertOrUpdatePatrol(SelectedPatrol);
        RefreshPatrolList();
    }
```

What i would like to achieve here is to add a row and retrieve it directly in my viewmodel in my binded property `SelectedPatrol` without leaving the selection of my row.

Currently when I'm clicking on my row button i just have an empty Object in my viewmodel side. But if i'm leaving the current selection then pushing the button in my new row freshly added, then my object is fill.
Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Cya guyz.

Comment: It seems that adding adding UpdateSourceTrigger on every columns helps a lot !

Comment: I am not following. SelectedPatrol is binded to the SelectedItem property of the DataGrid so this property should always be in sync with what is currently selected in the DataGrid. That's the purpose of this property. And adding a new row should be as simple as assing an object to the collection; Patrols.Add(new Patrol());

Comment: Indeed, its always sync as you mention but each binded column update datagrid only when you lost focus on the row. That's why we need to set the UpdateSourceTrigger property to propertyChanged because i want that change to be available before focus is lost.